# Disable USB keyboard and mouse input

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

On my Rpi I want to disable USB keyboard and mouse input completely. The RPi should respond only to ssh, not on local USB HID inputs. (other USB devices should still be allowed)

The following failed:

```
$ modprobe -r usbhid
FATAL: Module usbhid is builtin.
```

How can I disable the USB HID module, so that keyboard and mouse are no longer recognized?

Comment: You can't disable it that way if the module is compiled into the kernel.  You *might* be able to do something with "udev rules"...

Comment: You can disable local login for users - see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/disable-local-login-but-allow-ssh-831598/ . Do you have a reason to keep HIDs connected in the first place?

Comment: udev no longer supports disabling devices by their ID or type. I also want to disable input devices on RPi. RPi works as unattended card and USB-drive reader, so USB socket is freely available to users. I want them to use mass storage devices only.
As for now, I find no way of blocking USB input devices. Any hints?